# Test class not sure how to write for this code

Tags: unit-test

I have written following apex class:

```
public with sharing class Persmissionset
{
    @AuraEnabled 
public static PermissionPagerWrapper fetchPermission(Decimal pageNumber ,Integer recordToDisply) {
      Integer pageSize = recordToDisply;
      Integer offset = ((Integer)pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;

    // create a instance of wrapper class.
    PermissionPagerWrapper obj =  new PermissionPagerWrapper();
    // set the pageSize,Page(Number), total records and accounts List(using OFFSET)   
        obj.pageSize = pageSize;
        obj.page = (Integer) pageNumber;
        obj.total = [SELECT count() FROM PermissionSetAssignment Where Assignee.isActive = True AND permissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE];
        obj.permissonAssignment = [SELECT PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.Label, Assignee.Name, Assignee.Id, Assignee.Profile.Name,Assignee.ProfileId,Assignee.UserRole.Name,Assignee.Profile.UserType,Assignee.Email FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
       Where Assignee.isActive = True AND permissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE 
       ORDER BY Assignee.Name LIMIT :recordToDisply OFFSET :offset];
    // return the wrapper class instance .
        return obj;
     }

 // create a wrapper class with @AuraEnabled Properties    
 public class PermissionPagerWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled public Integer pageSize {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Integer page {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Integer total {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public List<PermissionSetAssignment> permissonAssignment {get;set;}
   }
```

But here  I am stuck in writing test class for this object.

Can some one help here as of now I am writing this test class but its giving error for me:

```
@isTest
public class PermissionsetTest
{
  static testMethod void PermissionTest()
  {
 List<> saList = Persmissionset.fetchPermission(10 ,100);

  }
}
```

Comment: It is comlaining about ```List<> saList```, you haven't mention any object for the List, however, your method returns PermissionPagerWrapper, so it is better to write smth like this: ```PermissionPagerWrapper ans = Persmissionset.fetchPermission(10 ,100);```

Comment: I tried using the above mentioned but getting invalid identifier error.

Answer (score 1):

`PermissionPageWrapper` is an inner class. In your test class, you must refer to it as `Persmissionset.PermissionPageWrapper`. This will allow you to correctly declare

```
List<Persmissionset.PermissionPageWrapper> saList = Persmissionset.fetchPermission(10 ,100);
```

and then write assertions.

To avoid being dependent on org configuration, your test class will have to do some work to create a test-context user and assign them a permission set, or you will need to use a mocking pattern to allow you to inject the query results so that you can actually page through results.

Comment: Thanks It works for us